# Change channel of pulseaudio default device

Tags: pulseaudio

I am using pulseaudio. I have set the Bluetooth as default device, it set perfectly but I wanted to change the channel of that default device. Can I change the channel of default device to right only or left only?

And how?

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:ffmpeg]? Are you using `ffmpeg`?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: Yes I am using ffmpeg for recording, so I wanted to change the channel at ffmpeg runtime